# Не могу настроить php окружение

Tags: php, xampp

Ребят, я сразу признаюсь я чайник, я верстальщик, хочу разобраться как мне сделать загрузку php файлов локально, я делаю корпоративный сайт, использую функцию inClude да и почта... в общем файлы переименовываю в php, раньше, чтобы их запускать локально использовал open server, потом появились проблемы он не видел в папке domains сайтов, я его бросил...

Сейчас поставил Xampp закинул в htdocs файл с доменом и о чудо он запустился локально, подумал, что боль позади и могу спокойно кодить, нет! внес изменения в файлы, добавил новые, и заметил что они не обновляются в папке htdocs, как будто кеш какой-то, начал гуглить, какие-то заумные статьи что-то куда-то внести ничего не понял, не разобрался в общем...

Народ может быть кто знает как мне легко работать с php локально? Или придется к старому способу возравщаться все обновления грузить на хостинг и уже там смотреть именения...

Comment: что значит не обновляются? вы закидываете файлы в htdocs, на локальном сервере?

Comment: да, у меня допустим в папке js, не было wrap.js я его туда поместил, чтобы убрать скрипт со страницы, но когда обновляю страницу во вкладке sourse папке js его вообще нет...

Comment: а вы данный файл в html подключили?)

Comment: конечно))) кстати если я закидываю этот скрипт на хостинг, он также не отображается... пришлось снова убрать его вниз страницы, чтобы работал

Comment: f12 в консоли смотри ошибки, возможно в пути косяк

Comment: да кстати) нашел, спасибо)

Comment: бывает, не за что)

Comment: рекомендую laragon

Comment: спасибо, вроде хорошая штука нужно попробовать поставить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

была проблема в путях к файлу)